# Using 64GB SD card, yet Play Store doesn't install apps because of insufficient memory

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, insufficient-memory

I am using Android 5.0 with a 64GB SD card  and I have approximately 500MB of memory left in the internal storage, but I am unable to install apps from Play Store on account of "insufficient memory for app size".

How to resolve this issue? Is there any way to install apps directly in SD card?

Comment: Maybe if you had 6.0 Marshmallow we could try something along your suggested lines, but not now.

Comment: The [wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) of the tag [tag:insufficient-memory] should help you understand the issue. Also,  did you thoroughly search/research for an answer before asking your question?  Tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far and why it didn't meet your needs? This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to your problem:

- Moving apps from internal memory to SD card (not necessary external SD card).

  This will allow you to install apps on the internal memory while the data of the apps (which is usually bigger then the app itself) will be stored on your SD card. This is will give you a lot of free space for more apps of your choice. Downside is, every app you move to the SD card will not have a widget and will be slower to use. You can do this by installing App2SD from Play Store or any other app that can move other apps.
- Different approach requires more technical skills.

  You can root your device and manually change the partitions so you get more space on your "apps partition", but less in system partition or cache partition. This procedure is a bit tricky and is different for each device. If you decide to do this a good starting point is the XDA developers forum or simply Google it for your specific device.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings` > `Apps`. Choose already installed applications and move them to SD Card. (Preferably apps other than Play Store, Google Apps, etc, which may not be movable )

Answer (score 0):

I use AppMgrIII, I ALWAYS root my devices therefore enabling me unrestricted access to my devices. You can move apps to your SD Card in bulk with root access within AppMgrIII. Even those that fault under "boot complete" call.

Comment: Link to the app please?

Answer (score -1):

When you uninstall an app from your Android phone it doesn't actually remove everything. The APK is hidden away still, therefore, using unnecessary storage.

I'd say the simplest way to resolve this is to clear up some space (photos, videos and more) and download CleanMaster. It clears out anything that doesn't need to be there and can even improve performance.

If you can't clear enough space with CleanMaster, it's probably worth your time to plug your phone into your PC and navigate through until you find the APKs and manually delete them yourself.

Comment: Well that's odd. With my old Sony Xperia M2 it used to tell me I had insufficient storage, despite uninstalling all of the apps I downloaded from the play store. The only way I resolved this was by plugging it into my PC and delete the APKs myself.

Comment: How did you navigate to the apk files while connected to PC? PS. No one is rude to you.

Comment: That is factually incorrect. Uninstalling an app installed from the Play Store does delete its apk file unless it had been sideloaded and the original apk was left on-device in the internal or external SD card and/or backed up to the SD card, using an app say ES File Explorer.